# Selecting only one row if the same ID - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to learn SQL commands and working currently with an query which will list all customers which has status `active (ID = 1)` and `active-busy (ID = 2)`.

The problem is that some customers have the same ID but the different type. So I have an customer which has ID 1 and Type 3 but the same customer has also ID 1 but Type 1 so what I'm trying to do is select only this which has Type 1 but have also the same ID. So IF ID is the same and Type is 1 and 3, select only Type 3.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN corel.opts LIKE 3
          THEN (SELECT corel.opts
                WHERE corel.objid = rel.id
                  AND corel.type IN (1, 2)
                  AND corel.opts = 3 
          ELSE corel.opts 1 
    END)
```

It's not complete query because it has many other this which I can't post but if you guys would show me way how could I accomplish that, I would appreciate it. I just don't know how to tell IF the same ID in the table but different Type - select only Type 3. Each customer have different ID but it can have the same type.

Comment: Take a look at the ROW_NUMBER() functionality - it'll help you tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

USE Row_number() like this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    TypeNo INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(4,3)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY TypeNo DESC),
        Id,
        TypeNo
        FROM @T
)
SELECT
    Id,
    TypeNo
    FROM CTE
        WHERE RN = 1
```

My Input

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Test scenario is borrowed form Jayasurya Satheesh, thx, voted your's up!

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    TypeNo INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(4,3)
```

--The query will use `ROW_NUMBER` with `PARTITION BY` to start a row count for each `T.Id` separately.
--`SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` will take *all first place rows* and not just the very first:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    Id,
    TypeNo
FROM @T AS T
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.Id ORDER BY T.TypeNo DESC)
```

If your `Type=3` is not the highest type code the simple `ORDER BY T.TypeNo DESC` won't be enough, but you can easily use a `CASE` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need something like:

```
SELECT c1.* 
FROM corel c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN corel c2 ON c1.objid=c2.objid AND c1.type <> c2.type
WHERE (c1.type=1 AND c2.type IS NULL) OR (c1.type=3 AND c2.type=1)
```